# Do I have to show the product description on my IOS app. for a non-consumable product?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Do I have to show the product description to the user before he/she proceed to buy? so my app. got accepted by apple.

Comment: Why would you want not to show the user what they are buying?

Comment: the interface provided by my client don't have a place for that. And it will look bad if I tried to add it on the existing design

Comment: I did finish all functionalities. that's the last thing. I will publish in 2 days.

Comment: I am selling videos for children's and the title and the picture is enough.

Comment: I found this: After setting up the unique app identifier and enabling it for IAP I was able to configure a simple non-consumable product with price tier 1 and localizations for English and German. At minimum you have to have one language even though you might never display the localized title or description. on the following link: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/things-i-learned-implementing-my-first-inapppurchase/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an experiance and depending on this [link](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/things-i-learned-implementing-my-first-inapppurchase/).

You have to decide what is clear enough to display. On my case, image and title was enough.

Apple people, will use the same since about what is enough and what is not.